# aggreagtate the overall data based on week and sum all the values for that particular week

Tags: python

I have a csv file with data such as:

```
from datetime import datetime
import random
pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(datetime.today(), periods=100).tolist(),
             'country': random.sample(range(1,101), 100),
             'amount': random.sample(range(1,101), 100),
             'others': random.sample(range(1,101), 100)})
```

I wish to sum the columns records for a week. Example, 2020-05-01 to 2020-05-07 will be one week so it will sum the amount and total it for this week. This should continue until the end of data and the output I wish is something like:

Example output:

```
date              country amount  others
month 5 week 1     100     50     50
month 5 week 2      30     60      60
month 5 week 3      50      70     666
month 5 week 4       60      100     445
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its not the exact what you are looking for but one way of doing is using the pd.Grouper method:

```
In [74]: res = df.set_index('date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W-MON'))[['country','amount','others']].sum().reset_index(
    ...: )

In [75]: res
Out[75]:
         date  country  amount  others
0  2020-04-20      257     412     344
1  2020-04-27      392     335     259
2  2020-05-04      294     263     363
3  2020-05-11      350     341     245
4  2020-05-18      394     277     330
5  2020-05-25      398     305     341
6  2020-06-01      398     338     509
7  2020-06-08      324     364     421
8  2020-06-15      435     415     430
9  2020-06-22      431     365     352
10 2020-06-29      330     275     358
11 2020-07-06      326     384     308
12 2020-07-13      368     473     364
13 2020-07-20      278     387     362
14 2020-07-27       75     116      64

In [86]: res['month'] = res['date'].dt.strftime('%b')

In [87]: res['weeknum'] = res['date'].apply(lambda x: x.isocalendar()[1])

In [88]: res.head(10)
Out[88]:
        date  country  amount  others month  weeknum
0 2020-04-20      257     412     344   Apr       17
1 2020-04-27      392     335     259   Apr       18
2 2020-05-04      294     263     363   May       19
3 2020-05-11      350     341     245   May       20
4 2020-05-18      394     277     330   May       21
5 2020-05-25      398     305     341   May       22
6 2020-06-01      398     338     509   Jun       23
7 2020-06-08      324     364     421   Jun       24
8 2020-06-15      435     415     430   Jun       25
9 2020-06-22      431     365     352   Jun       26
```

It would group the dates on a weekly frequency. More details can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html). Here the week number is based on a yearly basis.

Comment: thank you sir but how come the separation for year 2019 is so different than for 2020 when using your recommended code? for example, year 2019 for first week it is from 2019-01-1 to 2019-01-07 while 2020 is 2020-01-01 to 2020-01-06. Please shed lights.

Comment: i wish to have both multiple years to have the same date range for weekly group

Comment: since the frequency set is W-MON which means Weekly and every Monday, the week count increases after every Monday, in 2019 the first Monday is on 07 so your first week includes till 07 while in 2020 the first Monday comes on 06 so you have a shorter week.

Comment: by default it calculates the weeks based on Sunday i.e if freq=W.

Comment: Thank you sir, but how can I make it so that all years to become at 6?

Comment: no basically, the grouping depends upon the day of week. So at the start of the year and at the end of year, you may have a smaller week.